# Is RealmBaseAdapter removed from realm-java?

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to use an example from realm-java on github and figured that RealmBaseAdapter has been removed from io.realm package. Where is it being saved now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It has been split into a separate dependency as of Realm Java v0.90. Per the [Adapters section of the Realm Java documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters), you should add the following to your `build.gradle` to use `RealmBaseAdapter`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, bdash